# hostapd debug level configuration

Tags: wifi, hostapd

From what I understand so far, hostapd is a binary which is able to do some network configurations.

However, to enable hostapd debug level, do I need to rebuild the binary? Is there any other approach I can take instead of rebuilding a new one ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Executing `hostapd` with no arguments reveals that specifying `-d` or `-dd` enables debug messages:

> `-d` show more debug messages (`-dd` for even more)

It is also possible to configure the event logger verbosity via [`hostapd`'s configuration file](http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf):

```
# hostapd event logger configuration
#
# Two output method: syslog and stdout (only usable if not forking to
# background).
#
# Module bitfield (ORed bitfield of modules that will be logged; -1 = all
# modules):
# bit 0 (1) = IEEE 802.11
# bit 1 (2) = IEEE 802.1X
# bit 2 (4) = RADIUS
# bit 3 (8) = WPA
# bit 4 (16) = driver interface
# bit 5 (32) = IAPP
# bit 6 (64) = MLME
#
# Levels (minimum value for logged events):
#  0 = verbose debugging
#  1 = debugging
#  2 = informational messages
#  3 = notification
#  4 = warning
#
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
```

Comment: Is there a way to let hostapd to log MAC addresses which attempted to connect but not yet added into hostapd.accept? I tried log level 4 but still not find such info in the logs.

Comment: First of all, try log level 0, which is the most verbose one. Secondly, the log message won't necessarily include a descriptive reason. You can inspect [`hostapd`'s source code](https://w1.fi/cvs.html) and see how the code behaves after returning from the functions `hostapd_allowed_address(...)` and `hostapd_check_acl(...)` (the former invokes the latter) in order to know what to expect.

Comment: Thank you, Yoel!